# Integrate custom lightning web application with chatter

Tags: lightning-web-components, chatter, chatter-feed

I am trying to integrate my custom application I built with the help of the LWC with chatter so that user can post notes or send emails from application. I tried searching on google on how to do this, I found the way for aura components, but not for web components. Is there any way to add chatter functionality to lighting web application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's currently a JavaScript-only way to access Chatter, but you can use the [ConnectAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm) methods in Apex to perform various actions.

Comment: What about dropping a Chatter component onto your LWC like you can in a Flexipage?